# Counting number of characters using textViewDidChange in ios

Tags: ios

I have search this problem every where but i am not getting my result.
I have set textview as delegate.
I want to display the number of count in label "counter" 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{  
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textView.text];
    //if message has text show label and update with number of characters using the NSString.length function
    if (substring.length > 0) {
           self.counter.hidden = NO;
        self.counter.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d characters", substring.length];   
    }
    //if message has no text hide label
    if (substring.length == 0) {
        self.counter.hidden = YES;
    self.counter.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d characters", substring.length];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? How does this not work? Is the method never called, or are the results in some other way not as you expect?

Comment: Side note - replace `NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textView.text];` with `NSString *substring = textView.text;`. No need to create a new string.

Comment: Method was never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just hides the label but never shows it, when first characters arrive.

Instead of:

```
if (substring.length == 0) {
    self.counter.hidden = YES;
```

... always set the visibility:

```
self.counter.hidden = substring.length == 0;
```

Comment: @user3763512 If you really want help with this we need more information than "doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks it works :) Sorry i am new here thats why don't know how to ask further.

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSUInteger strLength = (textView.text.length - range.length) + text.length;
    return YES;
}
```